# Can I do a URL Rewrite to a different Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Is is possible to use [Tuckey's URL Rewrite](http://groups-beta.google.com/group/urlrewrite?pli=1) to rewrite to a different Tomcat instance?
I have it working using `crossContext="true"` rewriting to a different servlet on the same tomcat instance, but our production server has multiple tomcat instances running and I want to rewrite to one of them instead?

If it's not possible using the URL Rewrite filter, is there another way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Apache in front of your Tomcat instance?

Comment: I do on production, not on my dev instance

Comment: If production is using Apache then you should probably go the mod_proxy or mod_jk route and just start using Apache in your Dev environment.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that if possible. It's not a straight rewrite - I was using values from the original servlet to add to the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply rewrite to another instance. You'd either have to fetch the content from another instance (e.g. using `new URL("http://localhost:8081/foo").openConnection()....´) or redirect the client using a 30x redirect. If you have a proxy in front of your Tomcats, you might be able to configure it to resolve the redirect directly instead of sending it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proxy the request then you need to use mod_jk or mod_proxy in Apache to proxy the request to a different machine. If you are OK with issuing a redirect then it should work fine with just URL Rewrite.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, Apache isn't an option as the request was already forwarded to a Tomcat instance. It it would be possible to redirect directly to the correct instance from a proxy the question would be more or less obsolete anyway.

Comment: I was implying that he would need to put Apache in front of his Tomcat instance and then handle the proxying with Apache.