# How to redirect Domain Name in java

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I want to redirect user's request url like `http://site/a/index.html` to `http://a.site/index.html`. And further more keep user browser's url not changed.
Does urlrewrite(http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) support this? How should I implement this?
I need to change the url because I can not alter DNS server.
Thank you!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504173/can-i-do-a-url-rewrite-to-a-different-tomcat-instance

Answer (score 0):

It should work, since it claims to be the JSP equivalent of mod_rewrite. Also, if you want to redirect `http://site/a/index.html` to `http://a.site/index.html`, you could use HTTP redirection, or just a simple

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```